# Angular multiple favicons depending on environment

Tags: angular, angular-cli, environment, favicon, angular9

I recently moved to Angular 9 and I have multiple environments for production for my app, and each of them should set its own favicons, but I'm not sure how to do so.

I also want to set multiple favicons for all devices and sizes, so I have multiple files at once (favicon,  favicon-16x16, favicon-32x32, etc.)

AFAIK I can't use variables in my index.html, so should I create one index per each env with its own favicons?

Also how can I change default favicon.ico with all these I have?

Comment: You could use the `environnement.{env name}.ts` files inside the `environnement` folder of the `src` folder. You could set a variable in there that is the favicon and when your app is compile to said environnement, this variable will be used.

Comment: I've built a small library in order to manipulate the favicon in case it's of any help :) https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-favicon you could then read from your environment which favicon you need to display

Comment: Nicolas, how can I use it from index.html? I don't get it. Or should add link tag from main.ts to index?

Comment: @maxime1992, thanks for the lib, but it's not quite for my case. I don't need to change favicon in the app after building. I only need to put right favicons while building for particular env.

Comment: Oh right I see. Swap the asset depending on the pipeline then?

Comment: @maxime1992, yeah, I already did exactly that, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out that I can set different assets for each build and exclude the folder which I'm moving, and I'm doing smth like:

```
{
  ...,
  "configurations": {
    "production.one": {
      ...,
      "assets": [
        {
          "glob": "**/*",
          "input": "src/assets/favicon/production_one",
          "output": "assets/favicon"
        },
        {
          "glob": "**/*",
          "input": "src/assets",
          "output": "assets",
          "ignore": ["favicon/**/*"]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```